# Excel VBA: Running a shell script to both change directory and then run a custom script

Tags: shell, excel, csv, vba

I am trying to run this cmd script using vba which basically merges all csv files in a directory and then adds the filename of each file into a column at the end.

```
for /f %a in ('dir /b *.csv') do for /f "tokens=*" %b in (%a) do echo %b,%a >> all.csv
```

The problem I have is how to run this command in Excel Vba, while changing the default directory before running the above code.

This is because the `for /f %a in ('dir /b *.csv')` bit just takes your default directory in the cmd window. In the actual cmd window, I can just use the cd command, but no idea how to automate this with vba.

[Link to the original post for the code](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/322603-merge-csv-files-and-create-a-column-with-the-filename-from-the-original-file)

Any ideas guys?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a method for running your code from VBA excel.  I hard coded the path because I'm not sure what your input method will be.

```
Sub mergeCSV()
    Dim myDir As String
    myDir = "C:\Users\username\compile\"

    Dim strCommand As String
    strCommand = "for /f %a in ('dir /b *.csv') do for /f ""tokens=*"" %b in (%a) do echo %b,%a >> all.csv"

    Call Shell("cmd.exe /k cd /d " & myDir & " & " & strCommand, 1)
End Sub
```

The `Shell` call first opens the command prompt and then changes the current directory to the one specified in the `myDir` variable.  Then it runs the second command which I put in it's own variable `strCommand` to make it easier to read and follow.  You can make it so the window doesn't stay open by replacing `/k` with `/c`

I had two files for test, one with numbers and one with alpha characters.  Result file `all.csv` looks something like this:

[image]